# ReactJs how to replace new values in a map

Tags: reactjs

I have the below object. Need to replace values one of the keys ( values)

```
    var model ={ 
    n1 :{ values:{a1, b1}, 
          temp :set
         }, 
    n2 :{ values:{true}, 
          temp :set
        }
    }
    
    I want replace value for key n1 as 
     n1:{ 
     values:{true, false}, temp :set
     }
    please suggest the correct way of doing this
```

Comment: `values:{a1, b1}` this seems incorrect. Is values an array?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this, please look into this code -

This will change exact the values inside n1. the rest of the data will remain same as current state. Here useState used for seeing change in client layout.

```js
const model ={ 
 n1 :{ 
      values:{a1, b1}, 
      temp :set
 }, 
 n2 :{ 
      values:{a1}, 
      temp : set
 }
}

const [state, setState] = useState(model);


const handleAction = (newValues) => {
   
   setState({
     ...state,
      n1: {
       values: {a1: newValues.a1, b1: newValues.b1}
       ...state.n1,
      }
   })
}
```

If you don't need to visualize it in client layout. Just look into this below code -

```js
let model ={ 
 n1 :{ 
      values:{a1, b1}, 
      temp :set
 }, 
 n2 :{ 
      values:{a1}, 
      temp : set
 }
}

model = {
     ...model,
      n1: {
       values: {a1: false, b1: false}
       ...model.n1,
      }
   }
```

Comment: The key names are dynamic (n1, n2) . I am not sure what all keys will be there . I just need to update values to true or false for all . If a1 set it true , else false